# Why aren't fadeIn and animate duration working for my code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to change the opacity of an object instead of fading in content that was completely hidden so I changed

```
$(".thumb").each(function(i) {
    $(this).delay(500*i).fadeIn(1000);
});
```

to

```
$(".thumb").each(function(i) {
    $(this).delay(500*i).animate({'opacity' : 1}, 1000, function(){});
});
```

and the css from display:none to opacity: 0; (in all browsers) but I noticed that the numeral value **1000** isnt doing anything at all.. Maybe it is and I'm not noticing, but I have changed that form 1 to 100000 and I see no difference. Could someone help me understand whats going on?

edit: here is the full code.. maybe something is altering the fade in?

```
//Showcase
$('#showcase').animate({'opacity' : 0}, 0);
fadeInDivs(['#showcase']);

function fadeInDivs(els) {
    e = els.pop();
    $(e).delay(750).animate({'opacity' : 1}, 1000, function(){
        if (els.length)
            fadeInDivs(els);
    });
};

$('#showcase').queue(function(){
    //fade in each filter
    $('#filters li').each(function(i, item) {
        setTimeout(function() { $(item).animate({'opacity' : 1}, 1000); }, 500 * i);
    });

    //fade in each thumbnail
    $('.thumb').each(function(i, item) {
        setTimeout(function() { $(item).animate({'opacity' : 1}, 1000); }, 500 * i);
    });
});
```

this is what was causing the problem..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var $container = $('.isosort')
// initialize Isotope
$container.isotope({
        // options...
        resizable: false, // disable normal resizing
        layoutMode : 'fitRows',
        animationEngine : 'best-available',

        // set columnWidth to a percentage of container width
        masonry: { columnWidth: $container.width() / 5 }
});

// update columnWidth on window resize
$(window).smartresize(function(){
        $container.isotope({
        // update columnWidth to a percentage of container width
        masonry: { columnWidth: $container.width() / 5 }
        });
});
    $('#filters a').click(function(){
        var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
        $container.isotope({ filter: selector });
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

its at the bottom of my index.php file right before the `</body>` tag.. is there a better place to put this?

Comment: It is working as it should be. You aren't just noticing it. The 1000 value in animate is the time for the animation to complete. If you increase the animate time you will also have to increase delay to see relative delay. Otherwise the animation will start at  intervals of 500ms and all animation will end @ 500 x i ms.

Comment: @tamilsweet I tried to test this by changing the 1000 to 10000 and the 500 to also 10000 and the time it takes to get the opacity from 0 to 1 is still pretty much the same speed.. I would like to slow it down, I jsut cant figure out how..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you want

```
$(".thumb").each(function(i, item) {
    setTimeout(function() { $(item).animate({'opacity' : 1}, 1000); }, 500 * i);
});
```

Comment: What is the difference between this and the one I had? and thanks!

Comment: I think `delay` is called between animation calls on the same item.  `$("div.first").slideUp(300).delay(800).fadeIn(400);`   http://api.jquery.com/delay/

Answer (score 0):

> I noticed that the numeral value 1000 isnt doing anything at all

What are you expecting it to do?  It is the time the function takes, in milliseconds, to finish its animation cycle.

See:

- http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/
- http://api.jquery.com/animate/

See this fiddle:

- http://jsfiddle.net/UsMAD/

The higher you set the value, the longer it takes the `fadeIn` or `animate` to completely fade in the element.

### Update:

> updated top post with the whole javascript that animates the page

The new code hides the `#showcase`, but doesn't hide the `#filters li` or `.thumb` elements.  So when you fade in the showcase, the filters and thumbs are already visible.  The `fadeIn` effect applied to them won't show, since you're already at 100% opacity.

Here's a modification to your code that should fix that problem.  In particular, I'm selecting all those items when setting the `opacity` value:

http://jsfiddle.net/eU9qU/

```
//Showcase
$('#showcase, #filters li, .thumb').css('opacity', 0);
fadeInDivs(['#showcase']);

function fadeInDivs(els) {
    e = els.pop();
    $(e).delay(750).animate({'opacity' : 1}, 10000, function(){
        if (els.length)
            fadeInDivs(els);
    });
};

$('#showcase').queue(function() {
    //fade in each filter
    $('#filters li').each(function(i, item) {
        $(item).delay(500*i).animate({'opacity' : 1}, 10000);
    });

    //fade in each thumbnail
    $('.thumb').each(function(i, item) {
        $(item).delay(500*i).animate({'opacity' : 1}, 10000);
    });
});
```

Comment: thats what i thought it was for, but when i changed the number it didnt change the amount of time it took to fade in at all

Comment: @JoeBobby: It is on my end - What browser are you using?  I'm on a beta track of Chrome, tho I suspect this should work correctly in most browsers.  It doesn't change the time between the items *starting* to fade in, just the time it takes to become fully opaque.

Comment: @JoeBobby: I've tried it in Firefox 8.0.1 and IE9, and the change is also working for me.

Comment: im using firefox 8.0.1 so it should be working i would think.  I know the "500" controls how long it takes before it even starts to fade in so im not sure why im not seeing any difference when i change the number from 1000 to something else

Comment: updated top post with the whole javascript that animates the page.. not sure if it helps, but maybe its something im not noticing

Comment: the opacity for #filters li and .thumb is set in css, would i need that part in my script if its set in css?

Comment: @JoeBobby: No, tho you've already got jQuery setting the opacity for the `#showcase`.  Are these demos I'm sending working right in your browser?  Can you set up a jsfiddle that shows the problem you're having, including the CSS and specific HTML?  Maybe we've got a disconnect here...

Comment: found out what the problem was, it was another script that was interfering but im not sure how.. I placed the script in my first post at the bottom.. little confused on how to solve this one